# create object by new in on_pushButton_clicked() so where can i delete that object

Tags: qt, qt-creator

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  Model *model = new Model;
  ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}
```

Where can I delete model object, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do

```
  Model *model = new Model(this);
```

This will set `MainWindow` as parent of the `Model`. MainWindow will delete the object when it gets destroyed itself.

Read more https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html